# unable to read csv using panda from local

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage

I have below code to read csv which is working from cloud function

```py
import pandas as pd   
        file_name = "gs://" + "bucket_name" + "/" + name
        print(file_name)
        pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',')
```

But above code is not working from local, throwing error

```
_request out of retries on exception: Cannot connect to host storage.googleapis.com:443 ssl:True
```

I have tried with ping and its resonding...

I have also set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = project-name-xxxxx.json
```

Still its not working.

> I am able to get list of files from google storage, but unable to read data through pandas

Any help

Thanks

Comment: How do you mount your bucket?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file project-name-xxxxx.json` before `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = project-name-xxxxx.json` and make sure that you are mounting using the propper `gcsfuse` commands.

Also if you are not using a variable you don't need to use separate strings so just write `file_name = "gs://bucket_name/" + name` or remove quotation marks: `file_name = "gs://" + bucket_name + "/" + name`

Comment: variable name is just an indication... I already have gcloud auth login with admin privilege

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam How do you mount your bucket? Which command do you use while mounting? There seems to be no problem with your code, there is an error while mounting.